# Cannot display Img from gatsby-image

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I am trying to display an image using the `Img from 'gatsby-image'`. I am using graphql to pull the image data from the the `src/images` directory.

The query returns the data, and here is the console output :

```
file:
id: "f5c79f46-ac62-5305-9093-3087798d574f"
childImageSharp:
id: "60159a12-0e63-532a-b95a-9f2714358d00"
fluid:
base64: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAARCAYAAADdRIy+AAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAEX0lEQVQ4y32Ue0zbVRTH2/76freUR/srtLRllI1Hy1gZbUFYgQnZ0pUOxkbBdqU8xpopyGPA5mvq1skyfGCYkb0CA8N0A0OCOphZND3C0f6HyRCzWNs/CSeDYTmYZzs0fdkXai/N8BXzpLioH3IY/9P+BlacvQ3uuAHuAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
aspectRatio: 1.187279151943463
src: "/static/59ab759908e0dac65e98b73407125e75/7b9fb/bitmoji.png"
srcSet: "/static/59ab759908e0dac65e98b73407125e75/e1953/bitmoji.png 250w,↵/static/59ab759908e0dac65e98b73407125e75/7b9fb/bitmoji.png 336w"
sizes: "(max-width: 336px) 100vw, 336px"
```

however the image is not rendering to the page.  Here is the code for the component :

```
import { Link, graphql,useStaticQuery } from "gatsby";
import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react";
import './style.scss';
import bitmoji from '../images/bitmoji.png';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';

const Header = (props) => {
  const {siteTitle} = props;
  const imgQuery = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query {
    file(relativePath: {eq : "bitmoji.png"}){
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth : 1000) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
}`);

  return (
    <header className={scroll ? "nav scroll" : "nav"}>
        <div className="title">
          <Img fluid={imgQuery.file.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
          <Link to="/">{siteTitle}</Link> 
        </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the terminal or console?

Comment: No errors whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

If I copy your component, replace `bitmoji.png` with `gatsby-astronaut.png` it seems to work as expected.

```
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import React from "react"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const Header = props => {
  const imgQuery = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      file(relativePath: { eq: "gatsby-astronaut.png" }) {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <header>
      <div className="title">
        <Img fluid={imgQuery.file.childImageSharp.fluid} />
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: I tried using gatsby-astronaut.png but still nothing shows up.
```
const queryData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query {
    file(relativePath: {eq : "gatsby-astronaut.png"}){
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth : 1000) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
}`);```

Comment: Just to be clear, if you copy the above solution into your own header component, does it work?

Comment: correct.  The exact code does not render an image.  I have already installed the required plugins as well: 
```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },

Comment: Let's chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210038/gatsby-image

Comment: Hey @ksav.  I jumped into the chat, didn't hear from you.  let me know when you're free to chat